# Qt gridlayout square cells

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qt4

I have a screen ui file that has a grid layout and 8 buttons laid out something like this

```
 ---------------------
|                     | 
| 1     2     3     4 |
|                     | 
|                     |
| 5     6     7     8 |
|                     |
 ---------------------
```

The buttons have background images set. The images look weird on window resize when the buttons aren't square. I have to support resizing of the window. Is there a way to ensure the buttons are squares (equal width and height) all the time, no matter what the window size is?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [QGridLayout](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8/qgridlayout.html) with a few [QSpacerItems](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8/qspaceritem.html) (at the edges) to expand to fill extra space when the ratio of the whole widget is not 2:1.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

Use the `QPushButton::setFixedSize()`, and set the desired size to all your buttons.

This will prevent your buttons from shrinking/increasing in size, but if you make the window bigger, there will be space between your buttons. It may look weird as well.

Comment: well, fixed size is no brainer. My question was about having square button with resize support. The buttons have to grow/shrink with the parent window and also maintain the square aspect ratio. sorry if I didn't state that clearly in the question.